# Want to use sqlite database for an android application

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi,

I want to create a sqlite database for use in an Android application to store data for offline use. When there is no internet connectivity my application will show some data from this sqlite DB. Any pointers, where I should begin with?

Thank you

Comment: is there you want to show some sqlite db related webpages from your application when Internet is not available?

Comment: No i want to dsiplay data that is inside the sqlite DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "DATABASE_NAME", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE yourTable ("
                + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "name TEXT NOT NULL);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int o, int arg2) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS yourTable");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertMethod(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO yourTable (name) VALUES(?)";
        SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(insertQuery);
        stmt.bindString(1, name);
        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();
        db.close();
    }

    public String getMethod() {
        String name;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT name FROM yourTable LIMIT 1";
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();

        if(cur.isAfterLast() == false)
            name= cur.getString(0);

        cur.close();
        db.close();
        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: May i know how to call this class from the base class??

Comment: To create an instance of the database just write `DatabaseHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(this);`
and then to use the insert and get methods `database.insertMethod("String to insert");` and `String text = database.getMethod();`

Answer (score 1):

here is the article link for the database

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0):

you can create sqlite database dynamically or copy existing database to our workspace.

Refer this link: http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742

Comment: so do we have the exe of the sqlite DB?

Comment: what if i don't want to create dynamically?? Any other option is available?